# How to pivot map column in Cassandra to records having key as column name and Value as the value of column?

Tags: dictionary, cassandra, pivot, cassandra-3.0

I have defined a table in Cassandra. There is one column which is of map datatype. I want to implement Pivot on this column in a way that the key will become the column name and value associated with that key becomes the value of the column.
Is there any particular approach to do that? Do i have to define UDF or UDA in CQL? The Table definition, data and expected output is as follows:

````
     create table test_data(
        ... id int,
        ... product_name text,
        ... machine_address text,
        ... test_id int,
        ... result map<text,text>,
        ... PRIMARY KEY (id));

``` Table Data:
      id   | machine_address | product_name | result                                                                                       | test_id
------+-----------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------
 1101 |          AEI-T4 |        Saker | {'comment': 'Pass', 'start_time': '2018-02-06T00:00:00', 'stop_time': '2018-02-06T00:00:00'} |     124
 1103 |          AEI-T5 |       Saker2 | {'comment': 'Pass', 'start_time': '2018-05-07T00:60:00', 'stop_time': '2018-06-07T00:00:00'} |     141
 1102 |          AEI-T4 |       Saker1 | {'comment': 'Fail', 'start_time': '2018-02-07T00:60:00', 'stop_time': '2018-02-07T00:00:00'} |     124

The expected output after implementing Pivot on the map column 'result' should be like:

start_time          | stop_time           | comment
------+-----------------+--------------+------------
2018-02-06T00:00:00 | 2018-02-06T00:00:00 | Pass
2018-05-07T00:60:00 | 2018-06-07T00:00:00 | Pass
2018-02-07T00:60:00 | 2018-02-07T00:00:00 | Fail
````